# Agents "getting lost" when the number of agents to pickup is limited on a train carriage. (AnyLogic 8 PLE)

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to simulate a train network. When the number of agents is limited in the pickup block to "Quantity (if available)" to say 10, after picking up 10 agents, the rest of the agents are "lost" or remain in the waiting area, but never move after that.
[image: This is the general flow of the entire line]
[image: Here's the pickup block screen grab]

Any clue what I may be doing wrong here? The end goal is to limit the vehicle size and only allow a certain number of peds to enter the vehicle at any given time.

Thanks!

I tried to change the settings of the pickup block to achieve what I've been trying to do. My expectation was that the "Quantity (if available)" option would limit the number of peds entering the vehicle, but it seems like everyone boards anyway, the limit is taken and the rest are lost.
For example, if the limit is 10, in the stop duration, 30 may enter, 10 are offloaded at the destination, but the rest 20 are "lost".

Comment: Did you read the help (https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/pickup.html#pickup) ? How did you set the "Pick from" setting? Best always also share a screen of your block settings :)

Comment: I did go through this, and I thought I understood what's happening here. To understand the pickup and dropoff properly, I went through the given example on their website. [link](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/693bf957-2bbe-4866-83e5-78c1d9fbdd0e?mode=SETTINGS)
Even here, for example, say I want to restrict the number of people in each bus, when I change the parameters in the pickup block to "Quantity (if available)" to 10, the rest of the agents waiting in the bus stop get "stuck", or never move.

Comment: Or in other words, if the number of people in the waitBus area are 10, and I've said quantity is 5, the block should ideally go from 10 to 5 when a bus arrives. But in this case, it resets to 0 every time, and the remaining 5 agents are "lost".

Comment: The "pick from" setting, I've used both the queue connected to the port and tried specifying the actual queue, both give me the same results as described above.